# Fantasy trilogy. Boy named Ainsley(?) and a girl. Boy turns into dragon and then back again

Tags: story-identification

Years and years ago, I read a series of books in which two children, a boy and a girl, are sent/fallen/pulled into another world of fantasy through bodies of water. The boy's name is Ainsley, but I can't remember the girl's name. In one of the three books the boy is transformed into a dragon or something via magic, and eventually he is transformed back. In the third book there is a wizard, or old man, who guides them towards a gem/pearl/stone that embeds itself in the girl which grants her magical knowledge which ultimately prevents her from returning home.

Comment: THAT'S IT, you're awesome. I couldn't remember the title, and Google was no help.

Comment: Having a main character name is a lot of help

Comment: OP: this is a hard one. Valorum: Bish please.

Comment: Don't forget to click the "accepted" button (to the left of the answer) to show that this is the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

This is the [Silverskin Legacy](http://www.goodreads.com/series/81540-the-silverskin-legacy) series of books by Jo Whittemore, starting with '[Escape from Arylon](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1265443.Escape_From_Arylon)'.

> *Megan and Ainsley have lived next door to each other their whole
>   lives, but their relationship is anything but neighborly. Ainsley is
>   the cutest, most popular guy in school, and even has a group of girls
>   who call themselves his fan club. Outspoken and fiery, Megan is an
>   individual who thinks Ainsley is full of himself-and she doesn't mind
>   letting him know what she thinks. The two stumble upon a neighbor who
>   is performing some sort of strange magic, and find themselves
>   transported into a magical new world. Stuck together in an unfamiliar
>   land with no escape, Megan and Ainsley encounter floating cities
>   inhabited by magical creatures of all kinds-and find themselves
>   pursuing a thief who has stolen a staff with magical powers. Can Megan
>   and Ainsley work together to find the staff of power and save the
>   kingdom, or will they find that there is no escape from Arylon?*

[image]